# Coloring around divs within a flexbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a website's footer. In the image you see how it is supposed to be, and what I got. I was trying to get the location of my div called `secretarias` and the location of my div called `direita` because I wanted my blue divs to color AROUND these two, like in the image.

but jquery's location didn't work. And I'm not even sure it's a good way of doing that. I just want to color a couple of pixels more than what's colored around both these divs, and make that circular border around.

And also: I couldn't get div `"rights"` to be perfectly aligned on center. It's the only one that has a problem because its font size has got to be a little bit smaller than the others.

```js
/*
var position = $("#secretarias").position();
var bottom_l = position.bottom;
var left_l = position.left;

$("#rodapecor01").css("bottom: ",bottom_l, "left: ",left_l);

var position2 = $("#direita").position();
var bottom_r = position2.bottom;
var left_r = position2.left;

$("#rodapecor02").css("bottom: ",bottom_r, "left: ",left_r);

I couldn't make my JQuery work here but you can check it on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/552/
*/
```

```css
#rodape {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 27.5%;
 background: #e7e7dc;
 
 font-size: 3vh;
 font-family: PT_Sans-Web-Regular;
 text-align: center;
 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

#organizador {
 width: 48.60015522%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

#centro {
 width: 90%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}

#secretarias {
 width: 11.95230368%;
 background: #541324;
 color: white;
 text-align: right;
}

.linha {
 width: 4%;
 text-align: center;
}
.menurodape {
 text-align: center;
}

#direita {
 width: 39.4475411%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 background: #541324;
 color: white;
}

#mapadosite {
 
}

#rights {
 font-size: 1.5vh;
 text-align: center;
}

#rodapecor01 {
 /* background:#541324; */
 background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
}

#rodapecor02 {
 /* background:#541324; */
 background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  right: 5%;
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
}

#rodapelinha {
  background:#541324;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 27%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2%;
}
#whatimtryingtodo{
 background: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/60c6fb0a1d.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position:absolute;
 top: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
```

```html
What I'm trying to do:
<div id="whatimtryingtodo">
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
What I got:
<div id="rodapelinha">
</div>

<footer id="rodape">
  <div id="secretarias">SECRETARIAS:</div>
 <div id="organizador">
  <div id="centro">
   <div class="menurodape">DESENVOLVIMENTO</div>
   <div class="linha">|</div>
   <div class="menurodape">SAÚDE</div>
   <div class="linha">|</div>
   <div class="menurodape">EDUCAÇÃO</div>
   <div class="linha">|</div>
   <div class="menurodape">SEGURANÇA</div>
   <div class="linha">|</div>
   <div class="menurodape">CULTURA</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id = "direita">
  <div id="mapadosite">MAPA DO SITE</div>
  <div id="rights">© 2016 UNA-SUS/UFCSPA - Todos os direitos reservados </div>
 </div>
 
</footer>


<div id="rodapecor01">
</div>
<div id="rodapecor02">
</div>
```

Comment: You can compare this footer on snippet above (with flexbox) with this footer that i did without using flexbox (http://unasus.ufcspa.edu.br/cidadesvirtuais/SantaFe/1.0/layout.html). I think it's a lot better with flexbox I just would like to know how to solve these problems I've encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop your absolute positioned div's and add a border radius to your div's in question, you'll most likely get the desired result. (I also added a small padding to show how to make the colored area a little bigger)

Updated CSS rules

```
#secretarias {
  ...
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#direita {
  ...
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

For the text in `rights` element to center, I gave it `flex: 1`, and by doing that it will fill the remaining space and the text centers inside it.

Sample

```css
#rodape {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 27.5%;
  background: #e7e7dc;
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-family: PT_Sans-Web-Regular;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
#organizador {
  width: 48.60015522%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#centro {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#secretarias {
  width: 11.95230368%;
  background: #541324;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.linha {
  width: 4%;
  text-align: center;
}
.menurodape {
  text-align: center;
}
#direita {
  width: 39.4475411%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #541324;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#mapadosite {
}
#rights {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 1.5vh;
  text-align: center;
}
#rodapelinha {
  background: #541324;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 27%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="rodapelinha">
</div>

<footer id="rodape">
  <div id="secretarias">SECRETARIAS:</div>
  <div id="organizador">
    <div id="centro">
      <div class="menurodape">DESENVOLVIMENTO</div>
      <div class="linha">|</div>
      <div class="menurodape">SAÚDE</div>
      <div class="linha">|</div>
      <div class="menurodape">EDUCAÇÃO</div>
      <div class="linha">|</div>
      <div class="menurodape">SEGURANÇA</div>
      <div class="linha">|</div>
      <div class="menurodape">CULTURA</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="direita">
    <div id="mapadosite">MAPA DO SITE</div>
    <div id="rights">© 2016 UNA-SUS/UFCSPA - Todos os direitos reservados</div>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: Omg that was so simple! I could have aligned the div `rights` with `align-self: center;` too. And I switched `border-radius: 10px;` for `border-top-left-radius: 1em; border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;`. But I would never have guessed without you. Thank you so much! http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/615/